# Failure to display points from a MySQL table in QGIS

Tags: qgis-3, mysql

I connected a MySQL table containing points with QGIS.
Adding new records from QGIS works well.
The problem is this: QGIS does not display the points on the map. However QGIS manages to interpret the coordinates because it zooms on the area containing the points.
The attribute table in QGIS looks correct.
I work with QGIS desktop 3.4.14.1 in French. I also tried in English I have the same problem.

Precision : when I export the layer in 'kml' the coordinates of the points are exported correctly.

Comment: Are you sure it's not just a symbology problem (point to small to be seen or transparent or hidden under another layer or...). Please provide more information to get answers

Comment: For me it is not a problem of symbology. When the layer is active, I create a point, the symbol appears. When I save the layer, the database is incremented with the new record but the point disappears in QGIS.